# how to execute PowerShell commands from Windows server A so that it runs on Windows server B

Tags: powershell

Basically, i have PowerShell on both servers, is there a way to make a connection between both servers in such a way that when I run a command on PowerShell of Server A then it also runs on PowerShell of Server B.
I am new to PowerShell. Any help would be great.

Comment: `Get-Help New-PSSession`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `New-PSSession`-cmdlet in combination with the `Invoke-Command`-cmdlet

First of all create a remote session object:

```
  $remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName "YourComputerName" -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Afterwards, you can use the `$remoteSession` object to execute commands on the remote via:

```
 $servicesOnTheRemote = Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -Verbose -ScriptBlock { Get-Service * }
```

`Invoke-Command` runs `Get-Service` on the remote host, fetches the service state, serializes the data, and sends the data to the calling host. Based on that `$servicesOnTheRemote` includes the service state of the remote.

Also checkout this usefull [cheatsheet](https://blog.netspi.com/powershell-remoting-cheatsheet/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.I will check it soon.I have a batch script on Server B ,so shall i be able to execute it from server A using Powershell?..@Moerwald

Comment: Yes, should be possible.